# Venue API call for checkinsCount returns different values

Tags: java, android, json, api, foursquare

i am working on an android app using the Foursquare API. To test i use the APIGEE-console (http://www.apigee.com). Now i noticed some strange behaviour in the return values of the STATS/CHECKINSCOUNT.

For example this venue call: 
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4bdaaddcffafd13a6b109b85?v=20120321

Sometimes i get returned

```
"stats": {
        "checkinsCount": 8246,
        "usersCount": 2998,
        "tipCount": 12
```

When i call the api again, i sometimes get

```
 "stats": {
        "checkinsCount": 8214,
        "usersCount": 2990,
        "tipCount": 11
```

Anyone else noticed this before?

It seems to me Foursquare has some load balancing issues?

For my app, it is important to have the correct value (it's some kind of monopoly game and it's important to know the correct no. of visitors...)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is strange behavior!

We use Mongo as our database technology here at Foursquare. Since we're dealing with lots and lots of data coming in at an incredible rate, it's impossible for a single machine to handle storing and updating all the data we have to store and update. As such, we need to spread the load among several machines, as you guessed. As is bound to happen with any distributed system, we eventually run up against machine or connectivity failures.

Luckily, we have a [really excellent infrastructure team](https://foursquare.com/jobs) here who focus on keeping our database machines up and synchronized, so any issue caused by unsynchronized information is sure to be transient and short-lived (usually writes are distributed in a matter of milliseconds). It's also possible that what you saw wasn't a database issue and rather that some users deleted their accounts or that they were marked as cheaters, both of which could cause the legitimate stats on the venue's visitor count to decrease.

No matter what the cause was, the end result is that our API machines will always return to you what they believe to be exactly the correct value and you should go ahead and use it, but you shouldn't count on the value always being strictly increasing or as reflecting a check-in you have at-that-moment created.

Look forward to checking out your game!

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer. I understand the technical issues that can happen. Most of the problems, i can easily catch through my code so it's ok. FYI, the app is : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.verthosa.fourpolis  (working beta is released, but still a lot to add ;-) )